# Boolean string comparison in conditional attribute with MVC4 / Razor 2 returns unexpected results

Tags: css, attributes, asp.net-mvc-4, conditional-statements, razor-2

After upgrading my MVC 3 solution to MVC 4 with Razor 2 I came across the following problem.

This code in a view

```
@{
    string main = "archive";
}
    <div class="selected-@(main == "archive")"></div>
```

returns this in MVC 3

```
<div class="selected-True"></div>
```

and this in MVC 4

```
<div class="selected-class"></div>
```

which breaks my CSS.

Is that a bug introduced by the new conditional attribute feature in Razor 2?

My workaround is this:

```
<div class="selected-@((main == "archive").ToString())"></div>
```

which returns this:

```
<div class="selected-True"></div>
```

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bug-or-not question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13455272/533460

It's not a bug, it's a new feature of Razor 2!

What is happening in my code is based on this principle

```
<input checked="@ViewBag.Checked" type="checkbox"/>
```

becomes

```
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox"/>
```

when ViewBag.Checked == true.

So

```
<div class="@(main == "archive")"></div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="class"></div>
```

Thanks to @webdeveloper (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667969/webdeveloper) for pointing me to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative:

```
<div class="selected-@(main == "archive" ? "true" : "false")"></div>
```

Comment: But then with "True" and "False" because Boolean.TrueString is "True" not "true".

Comment: @FrankvanEykelen Thanks, I knew it, but if it possible I would recommend you, use naming conversion, it's easier to read.

Comment: @FrankvanEykelen Also look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455270/why-is-my-hidden-input-writing-value-value-instead-of-true-false

Answer (score 1):

Why not have this class as part of your view model, e.g.

```
public string MainClass {
            get { 
                if(main=="archive") return "True";
                return "False";
            }
}
```

and use this in your view

```
<div class="selected-@MainClass"></div>
```

Razor2 is more strict with it's view compilation.