# Why is my hidden input writing: value="value" instead of true/false?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 site, with (as part of a hidden form):

```
<input name="somefield" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Test"/>
```

The value of `ViewBag.Test` is `true`. The form field is posting to an input parameter of the form:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(bool somefield = false, ...)
```

but `somefield` is always `false`. Upon investigating, I see that the source code has:

```
<input name="somefield" type="hidden" value="value"/>
```

However, I *know* this used to work. What has happened, and what can I do?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451051/boolean-string-comparison-in-conditional-attribute-with-mvc4-razor-2-returns-u

Comment: And another related-but-different (nulls this time): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061647/conditional-html-attributes-using-razor-mvc3

Comment: I hope you've reported it as a bug.  That seems reasonable for things like `disabled` or `checked` but definitely wrong for `value`.

Comment: @tvanfosson I can see the logic of it - but it is a change. Not sure I'd call it a bug though. Breaking change, maybe

Comment: @MarcGravell I'd rather see less of a blanket solution and more of a targeted solution. Having said that, I haven't actually looked at the (new) code. Setting `value` to `"value"` seems definitely wrong. That, I think, is the bug.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This behaviour changed between MVC3 and MVC4. In MVC3, if you have:

```
<input name="somefield" type="hidden" someprop="@(SomeBooleanExpression)"/>
```

it would write very literally:

```
<input name="somefield" type="hidden" someprop="True"/>
```

However, in MVC4, it follows the "checkbox" etc rules, so if the value is `true` you get:

```
<input name="somefield" type="hidden" someprop="someprop"/>
```

and if it is `false` it is omitted completely:

```
<input name="somefield" type="hidden"/>
```

To get around this, consider `.ToString()`:

```
<input name="somefield" type="hidden"
   someprop="@(SomeBooleanExpression.ToString())"/>
```

which then follows string rules rather than boolean rules.

Comment: Has anyone noticed the behavior where if there is a space between the value property and the equals sign, then the boolean is evaluated and assigned as expected.  i.e. 'value =@(someBoolean)' will yield 'value="True"' whereas 'value=@(someBoolean) will yield 'value="value"'

Comment: @mcolegro heh, that's fun if true. Note there's Aldo a different behaviour for `@:` lines than for regular HTML blocks.

Comment: This worked, just when I think I understand areas like this in MVC4, I get hung up on things like this. Thanks for this answer, however, I don't get why it defaults to, "True", rather than "true" toLower() easily resolves this though.

Comment: `.ToString()` was the solution for me. Thank you so much! I was already doubting my eyes! What a behavior!

Answer (score -1):

initialized Boolean values **bool** something =false;

then convert this value into string like,

<input name="somefield" type="hidden" value="@something.ToString()>

```
                   OR
```

initialized **string** something ="false";
< input name="somefield" type="hidden" value="@something" >

then we can read

```
    public ActionResult Somemethod(bool something) => you can get Boolean value here 
    {
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer in a proper format.