# Sitecore MVC, input tags, and condition expressions as their values

Tags: input, lambda, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

There is some strange behavior being seen when setting the value attribute of an input tag to a conditional statement.  I am using the following code.

```
<input type="hidden" id="canAddAll" value="@(Model.WishList.Products != null && Model.WishList.Products.All(p => p.CanAdd))" />
```

The expected result of "value" for the input tag would be "True," but I am getting just the text "value."

```
<input type="hidden" id="canAddAll" value="value">
```

When looking at the compilation source, it looks like it is using a Tuple to create the value attribute in this case.  What is expected is a simple Write() for the value.

```
WriteAttribute("value", Tuple.Create(" value=\"", 272), Tuple.Create("\"", 382), Tuple.Create(Tuple.Create("", 280), Tuple.Create<System.Object, System.Int32>(Model.WishList.Products != null && Model.WishList.Products.All(p => p.CanAdd), 280), false)
```

Any ideas why I would be seeing this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can answer your specific question, however, i'd recommend placing the logic on the `WishList` model as a `CanAddAll` public bool property.

Comment: It is also possible to use the htmlHelper extensions for this: @Html.Hidden("canAddAll", Model.WishList.Products != null && Model.WishList.Products.All(p => p.CanAdd))

Answer (score 0):

Try to leverage Html.HiddenFor().

For full explanation, see accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18529322/435090